# pop up to another user of same application in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, interaction

I am using a php application. Here many users can login at same time like a web site.
Here a want when a user is saving form , a pop up should automatically appear on the browser of another user. id of 2nd user will be mentioned in form , when 1st user is savinf the form.

Please any body give me any idea.At least what type of technique i should use and what type of technology is required.

Thanks !
Rakesh

Comment: You'll have to use ajax, websockets, meta-refresh or alike.

Comment: Fixing tags since it's not php solely

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communication between browsers via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296306/communication-between-browsers-via-php)

Answer (score 2):

The technology you need is AJAX.

You should write a javascript function that calls periodically your server (through XMLHttpRequest) for any event you want to notify to your user,and when you have a relevant answer, that same function should pop up the warning.

You'll probably want to start using jQuery, a wonderful Javascript library (that includes Ajax calls) that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: just to add to what Yihad said, here is the official link for jQuery, you'll find it very useful http://jquery.com/